# Create OpenVPN file with L2TP/IPSEC credentials

Tags: configuration, openvpn, l2tp

I created a VPN from my windows server and I use it with L2TP credentials access (host, preshared key, login and password).

I downloaded a portable format of OpenVPN client for windows to put in USB key. The application can auto start with ovpn file but I don't known how to make this file. After some search I found the official documentation but there is a lot of arguments and I don't know  which ones to choose.

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage

Would someone here have already created a file for L2TP / IPSEC and could share an example?

Thanks